# How to find probability with two random values?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to find probability $P(\xi < \eta)$ if $\xi \sim Beta(1,2), \eta \sim Exp(1))$?  They're also independent.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess i should try find $\int F_{\xi}(t)f_{\eta}(t)dt$, because both these distributions are absolutely continuos.

Comment: You can start finding the pdf of $\xi$ and $\eta$

Comment: Then you know that the law of the couple $(\xi,\eta)$ is simply given by the product of the pdf's

Comment: The you identify the set over which to integrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{\xi<\eta\}} 2(1-\xi) e^{-\eta} \,d\eta\,d\xi
= \frac2e .
$$

Comment: What is the theoretical rule to count these probabilities?

Comment: @Daniil what do you mean? How to find the pdf's? That's the definition of beta and exponential distribution. How to compute the integral? Well, Fubini might come in handy...

Comment: I mean how do you come from the integral i wrote in the comments above to the double integral written here?

Comment: I don't know what the integral you wrote means. Maybe tell us what $F$ and $f$ are

Comment: I explained in the comments above the procedure. 1) find the pdf. 2) take the product measure. 3) integrate over the correct set

Comment: $\int\limits_{\Omega} F_{\xi}(t)f_{\eta}dt \leftarrow$ this one. $f = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

Answer (score 0):

$P(\xi < \eta)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\xi}^{\infty} 2e^{-\eta}(1-\xi) \text{d}\eta \text{d} \xi = \frac{2}{e}$

Comment: What is the theoretical rule to count these probabilities?